# Making changes to WordPress header.php through DashBoard

Tags: wordpress

First I take a copy of the header.php before I made changes.

After I made changes to the header like the default image and header text through the dashboard

I reopened the header.php and find no changes there.

My assumption is when changes being made through Dashboard then dynamically the corresponding php files would updated.  No?

If not, how would be changes in Dashboard be reflected in php file?

Comment: did you publish those changes ?

Comment: changes will publish same way as it is check the server permision for files  to read write

Comment: And you can add custom CSS through Jetpack

Answer (score 2):

If you're making your changes to the header.php files via **Appearances** >> **Editor** >> **Header.php** ... then of course you're altering your header.php file.

You can also accomplish this by FTPing the file or using your server's control panel.

But before you make all these changes to your core WordPress files, I'd have to ask -- "why"?  It's never (recommended) to make changes to your core WordPress files.  This is because when you go to update your WordPress the next time an update comes out, you'll **lose all your changes** ... so you'll have to keep a changelog of your edits or end up with a dinosaur version of WP in the future.

If your theme doesn't give you an opportunity to do so alter the header in other manners, perhaps a **plugin** is a better solution.  Or perhaps using **custom CSS** is a better solution if that fits your need.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Why would it need a moderation of a WP core file?  Most likely, there are other ways to accomplish your goal(s).

Comment: i am useing custom theme useing  twentytweleve and never  get updated when  wordpress updated it only apply to defoult theme if you are useing then all the changes get lost

Comment: Okay ... but what about when WordPress gets updated?  Currently it's at version 3.5.1 ...

Comment: no problum when wordpress get updated if you are make your theme not useing defoult one then it will not lost your changes  all  the updation apply on defoult theme  if you rename that then that will  not get updated

Comment: Vickey, that's just factually incorrect.  When you go to update to the next WP, the changes to your core WP files will be lost.  The upgrade process will affect all files and folders included in the main WordPress installation. This includes all the core files used to run WordPress, two plugins (Akismet and Hello Dolly) and three themes (Twenty Twelve, Twenty Eleven, and Twenty Ten). If you have made any changes to those files, your changes will be lost.

Comment: ok may be i have little knowledge but  i am tlking about the fourth theme by  unknown name  is that  correct  i am working that way

Comment: I don't understand the question.  But regardless, almost everything people want to accomplish can be accomplished by adjusting the custom CSS or using a plugin.  And if you must make changes to your core WP files, then you should keep a personal changelog of these and save it, so you know what files you've altered and how.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26421/discussion-between-vickey-and-jason-weber)

Comment: There is at least one reason to edit the header.php file directly: Google Tag Manager.  How else do you add the GTM noscript code just after the body tag...?